# Does curl retrieve data from REST API?

Tags: shell, rest, curl

I'm using a curl command to get the data from a REST API, and I would like to do an incremental pull every day to get the data from the API. So, using the curl command to download data into a CSV through a script daily, will I successfully pull all the data from the API?

Command used:

```
curl -O '-token-' https://example/api/views/ > data.csv
```

So I would like to keep the curl command in a script to download data everyday from the API and use the CSV for spreadsheets.

And does curl get all the data from the API or only today's data?
Or can I use a Python script to download data everyday?

Comment: cURL gets whatever data is on the API. If the API has daily data, then that is daily... Not sure what more you expect as an answer than "yes"

Comment: Thank you, I'm not sure of the cURL compared to wget, where cURL can get whatever the data in the API which is confirmed to your answer.

Comment: You never mentioned wget, and I'm also unsure why you even think you need Python

Comment: I was thinking to store the data as date partitions so I'm using Python for daily imports

Comment: There is a unix `date` command that would help with that

Comment: If the API is having around 30 Pages of data and would there be any parameter to pass ? Or we can run the above cURL command from page=1 to 30 ?

Comment: That is something that you'd have to determine on your own. No one would know about parameters to an API unless they're documented. And how do you define "a page" on the Internet? But yes, you can curl in a loop

Answer (score 0):

Yes. cURL can do this.

Look into doing the following:

1) Create a Bash script with your cURL command in it.
https://www.linux.com/learn/writing-simple-bash-script

2) Set up a Cron tab to execute the Bash script on a schedule.
http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ucrontab.htm

The above assumes you're using Linux, however you can achieve the same thing in macOS and Windows10 (using Bash for Windows).

My advise would be to create a droplet on DigitalOcean. There you can run a simple Linux server in the cloud that stays up and runs the above for you.

Comment: Windows Scheduler would be better than Bash for WIndows

Comment: Where is the fun in that? Yes, I think you're correct.